# Как можно просто и желательно в одну строчку "клонировать" список?

Tags: python, list, список

В изначальном виде код выглядел вот так:

```
a = [1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3]
for i in range(len(a)):
    b = a
    b.pop(i)
```

И предполагалось, что в каждом очередном проходе цикла `for`, список `b` будет представлять из себя список `а` без i-того элемента. Однако, в реальности, i-тый элемент выкидывался и из списка `a`, т.е., получается, что строка

```
b = a
```

не создавала еще один список `b`, который являлся точной копией списка `а`, а, по сути, присваивала одному списку два идетификатора `a` и `b`.

Избежать я этого смог следующим образом:

```
a = [1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3]
c = ' '.join([str(s) for s in a])
for i in range(len(a)):
    b = [int(s) for s in c.split()]
    b.pop(i)
```

Однако, я уверен, что это лишний огород.

Как же можно просто, безболезнено, и желательно в одну строчку, "клонировать" список?

Answer (score 13):

Клонирование списков:

- вариант 1:

  ```
  clone = my_list.copy()
  ```
- вариант 2:

  ```
  clone = my_list[:]
  ```
- [вариант 3](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/copy.html#copy.deepcopy):

  ```
  from copy import deepcopy

  clone = deepcopy(my_list)
  ```

Comment: Может на последний вариант дать ссылку на доку? Два первых то и так понятно.

Comment: @0xdb, сейчас добавлю)

Comment: Больше спасибо за ответ. Последний вариант мне не, конечно, не понятен, но попытаюсь по ссылке разобраться:)

Answer (score 4):

Изменяемые объекты передаются по ссылке. Это значит, что при изменении значения переменной объект будет изменен. К этому типу относятся:

- списки (`list`)
- множества (`set`)
- словари (`dict`)

**Подводные камни**

Создадим список `a`, установим для переменной `b` ссылку на `a`, прибавим к `b` элемент списка и выведем их значения и идентификаторы на экран:

```
a = [1, 2]
b = a
b.append(3)
print(a, b) # [1, 2, 3] [1, 2, 3]
print(id(a), id(b)) # 139748057891656 139748057891656
```

Как мы видим, переменные имеют одинаковые `id` и элементы списка. Если вы не знаете об этой особенности изменяемых объетов, то такое поведение программы становится полной неожиданностью и может привести к ошибке в работе программы.

Comment: Вот только на заданный вопрос это вообще никак не отвечает

Comment: @Xander будет автору в качестве дополнительной информации. Тем более ответ уже дали.

Comment: Спасибо больше за пояснение. Для меня это был вообще не очевидный момент