# Если я задаю новый словарь через существующий, то словари оказываются "связанными"

Tags: python, dict, key-value

Из обучалки делаю программу "аукцион".
Получаю словарь типа "имя":ставка

```
participant_list = {"vasia":20, "lena":30, "kolia":40, "frosia":10}
```

Потом методом перебора получаю "имя" победителя в примере `current_winner = "kolia"`
Далее хотел реализовать проверку нет ли двух победителей.

```
losers = participant_list
losers.pop(current_winner) #Исключаю из нового словаря победителя
```

При проверке выдавало ошибку. Как я выяснил - словарь `losers` и `participant_list` оказываются "связанными". При вызове метода `losers.pop(current_winner)` из `participant_list` также удаляется ключ `current_winner`. При это если сделать еще один словарь с точно такими же ключами, то в ней изменений не происходит. Вот финальный код, который показывает проблему:

```
participant_list = {"vasia":20, "lena":30, "kolia":40, "frosia":10}
current_winner = "kolia"
another_list = {"vasia":20, "lena":30, "kolia":40, "frosia":10}
print(f"participant_list до обработки:\n{participant_list}")
losers = participant_list
losers.pop(current_winner)
print(f"participant_list после losers.pop обработки:\n{participant_list}")
#здесь видно что в participant_list удалился ключ "kolia"
print(f"losers:\n{losers}")
print(f"another_list:\n{another_list}") #c another_list всё в порядке
```

Можете объяснить - почему словари оказываются "связанными", и как этого избежать?

Comment: это не библиотеки, а словари; participant_list и losers ссылаются на один и тот же объект, а another_list - на другой

Comment: Как создать новый словарь, чтобы они были отвязанными? через цикл?

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как можно просто и желательно в одну строчку "клонировать" список?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1123934/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%bd%d0%be-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d1%81%d1%82%d0%be-%d0%b8-%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d0%be-%d0%b2-%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%bd%d1%83-%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%be%d1%87%d0%ba%d1%83-%d0%ba%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%81%d0%bf%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%be%d0%ba)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"создать новый словарь, чтобы они были отвязанными" можно через deepcopy:

```
import copy

another_list = copy.deepcopy(participant_list)
```

это будут разные объекты и изменения одного не повлияют на второй:

```
>>> id(participant_list)
139904376722560
>>> id(another_list)
139904376428512

>>> participant_list.pop('vasia')
40
>>> participant_list
{'lena': 30, 'kolia': 40, 'frosia': 10}
>>> another_list
{'vasia': 40, 'lena': 30, 'kolia': 40, 'frosia': 10}
```

Но в вашем случае проще, на мой взгляд, найти имена победителей и записать их в список:

```
max_value_keys = [key for key in participant_list.keys() if participant_list[key] == max(participant_list.values())]
```

если у нескольких будет одинаковое максимально число:

```
participant_list = {"vasia": 40, "lena": 30, "kolia": 40, "frosia": 10}
max_value_keys = [
    key for key in participant_list.keys() 
    if participant_list[key] == max(participant_list.values())
]
```

то в итоговом списке будет несколько имен:

```
>>> max_value_keys
['vasia', 'kolia']
```

ps и не нужно ничего ниоткуда "попать" ;)

Comment: Спасибо за развернутый ответ